# Javascript fails because of double inverted comma in a test

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some text saved in my database in HTML format, This text was saved into datatbase from a email.

Sometimes emails have single or double opening inverted commas but no closing inverted commans.
Becuase of this other scripts on the page stop to work.
How can i prevent this html code which i am reading from database to not affect my page style or scripts.

You can consider my application to be simple email reading application. 
Any email that i read from database even if it has improper/buggy html, i don't want it to break my code.

Please let me know how i can fix this issues

I am working on following
- Laravel
- Bootstrap

Comment: Your emails have HTML content ? or do you just want to dump them as text on the page

Comment: I want show the email content in html format itself

Comment: find the quotes and replace it with escape sequences.

Comment: Thats the issue we dont know what the quotes will be. They are random emails.

Answer (score -1):

Always escape the data that you receive from the client or you will become a victim of XSS (Cross Site Scripting).

That said if you really want to do it then there are two ways so that the content of the email doesn't affect your code.

1. IFrame
2. Shadow DOM

Both of these have a separate context than the parent page so they will not interfere with your code unless the code inside them manually tries to access parent.

Following is the sample for both. [Same on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9ekca5s/1/)

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="iframeParent">
</div>

<div id="shadowParent">
</div>
<script>
    var emailContent = "<h1>helloworld</h1>";
    var iframeContainer = $("#iframeParent");

    $('<iframe/>').appendTo(iframeContainer).on("load", function () {
        $(this).contents().find("body").html(emailContent);//firefox
    }).contents().find("body").html(emailContent);//chrome

    var shadowContainer = $("#shadowParent");
    alert(shadowDom);
    var shadowDom = shadowContainer.get(0).createShadowRoot();
    shadowDom.innerHTML = emailContent;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** Shadom DOM is probably not the best solution as it's not enabled by default on the firefox. [See this link](https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2015/how-to-enable-web-components-in-firefox-shadow-dom/)